# Run methods on app installation

Tags: ios, swift

I want to prepopulate my database on app installation in the app store, so I have methods to retrieve data to put them in core data. It is possible ? Here is a method like onInstallation ?

Comment: you can do that in appdidfisniedlaunchingwithoptions. Just use Userdefauls to check first launch of the app

Comment: No, you cannot do anything during app installation!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not run code after installation.

Only on first start of your app can your run code, this would be the place to setup some data that your app needs.

If the data is not subject to change I would suggest you create the data store for CoreData with all the initial data and copy this on first run from the main bundle to the directory where you store your CoreData store.

If you need to fetch data you might want to display a screen to the user explaining that you setting up the app and that this might take some time depending on the user data connection.

Answer (score 0):

Not on install as far as I am aware, but how you could do is:

1 - in the `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "alreadyLaunch") as? Bool == nil || UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "alreadyLaunch") as? Bool == false{
        //populate your database    
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }

    return true
}
```

2 - After populating the database, add:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadyLaunch")
```